# Count how many rows are needed to add up to a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe

```
Acc_Name       gb
ABC            76
DEF            67
XYZ            50
RES            43
FEG            22 
HTE            0
DGE            0
```

The sum of GB column is 258 and its 80% is 206.4

I want the count,  how many rows if summed from top are less than or equal to the value 206.4 in the DataFrame.

Manually if I check I get the first 3 rows as answer, but how to get that using Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) for this:

```
df.gb.cumsum().lt(206.4).sum()
# 3
```

To do it all in one go:

```
df['gb'].cumsum().div(df['gb'].sum()).le(0.8).sum()
# 3
```

Comment: May be OP also wants `df['gb'].cumsum().div(df['gb'].sum()).le(0.8).sum()` :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help!, Can you also please explain me the working of ``df['gb'].cumsum().div(df['gb'].sum()).le(0.8).sum()`` so that I can understand the flow

Comment: I did not get the ``le(0.8).sum()`` part.  

Pt 1. ``df['gb'].cumsum()`` is finding the cumulative sum
Pt 2.  ``div(df['gb'].sum())`` is diving each cumulative row element by the total original sum
Pt 3. the ``le(0.8)``.sum()`` is where I am stuck at

Comment: `df['gb'].sum()` is the total sum. Dividing `df['gb'].cumsum()` by the sum will give the proportion with respect to the total at each step of the cumulative sum. `.le(0.8)` checks if the value is `less or equal` than 0.8, which results in a pd.Series of booleans. By taking the `sum` of the result you add up all `True`s. @Kimberly_Jennifer

Comment: Amazing, I got it now. Thank you so much again for the kind help.